# Sum all named fields in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to calculate the sum of all the values below. I have tried googling the question in different ways but cannot find an answer. The data looks like this.
I don't care about the keys, I am just looking for a total of the values  for monday

```
"monday" : {
                "a" : 5,
                "b" : 2,
                "c" : 1,
                "d" : 2,
                "e" : 3,
                "f" : 9,
                "g" : 2,
                "h" : 16,
                "h2" : 8,
                "g" : 2
                }
```

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ps0-te2yZeE

Answer (score 3):

You can use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) to convert `monday` into an array of `k` and `v` fields and then use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to sum them:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            sum: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$monday" },
                    initialValue: 0,
                    in: { $add: [ "$$value", "$$this.v" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/spmurwW1p2B)